# Отправка API запроса на OpenProject через Guzzle клиент

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

Пытаюсь отправить post api запрос через Guzzle на Api OpenProject, через Postman отправка прошла, теперь пробую отправить через Guzzle -> 422 ошибка, недопустимое свойство.

Код ошибки :
Client error: `POST https://tracker.dev.devspark.ru/api/v3/projects/26/work_packages` resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response:
{"_type":"Error","errorIdentifier":"urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:PropertyConstraintViolation","message":"Тема

Попытка создать задачу в проект на OpenProject

```
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => env('OPENPROJECT_API'),
            'auth' => ['apikey', env('OPENPROJECT_TOKEN')],
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        ]);


             $data = [
                json_encode([
                    '_type' => 'WorkPackage',
                    '_links' => [
                        'href' => '/api/v3/priorities/8',
                        'title' => $request->priority,
                    ],
                    'description' => [
                        'format' => 'markdown',
                        'html' => '<h1>' . $request->subject . '</h1><br>' . '<p>' . $request->description . '</p>',
                        'raw' => $request->description,
                    ],
                    'dueDate' => null,
                    'percentageDone' => 0,
                    'scheduleManually' => false,
                    'startDate' => null,
                    'subject' => $request->subject,
                ])
            ];

        $response = $this->client->post('projects/' . $projectData[0] . '/work_packages', $data)->getBody()->getContents();
```

Пытался и через ['json' => 'массив без json_encode()'] и через 'body', тогда выдает
500 , недопустимый контент... Может быть кто то сталкивался с этим ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        $data = [
            'json' => [
                '_type' => 'WorkPackage',
                '_links' => [
                    "priority" => [
                        'href' => '/api/v3/priorities/8',
                        'title' => 'High',
                    ]
                ],
                'description' => [
                    'format' => 'markdown',
                    'html' => '<h1>' . $request->subject . '</h1><br>' . '<p>' . $request->description . '</p>',
                    'raw' => $request->description,
                ],
                'dueDate' => null,
                'percentageDone' => 0,
                'scheduleManually' => false,
                'startDate' => null,
                'subject' => $request->subject,
            ]
        ];
```

В остальном все так же, ошибка в массиве передаваемом, потерял аргумент